# How to mock Twilio using Jest and TypeScript for unit testing

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, twilio

I need your help to mock a twilio service which sends a message, using jest to mock the service
I have the next code:

```
import { SQSEvent } from "aws-lambda";
import { GetSecretValueResponse } from "aws-sdk/clients/secretsmanager";

export async function sendSms(event: SQSEvent, data: GetSecretValueResponse) {
    const secrets = JSON.parse(data.SecretString);
    const accountSid = secrets.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
    const authToken = secrets.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
    const twilioNumber = secrets.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER;

    if (accountSid && authToken && twilioNumber) {
        //Create a Twilio Client
        const client = new Twilio(accountSid, authToken);
        //Loop into al records of the event, every record is every message sent from Sqs
        for (const record of event.Records) {
            const body = JSON.parse(record.body);
            const userNumber = "+" + body.number;
            //SendMessage function
            try {
                const message = client.messages.create({
                    from: twilioNumber,
                    to: userNumber,
                    body: body.message,
                });
                return message;
            } catch (error) {
                return `Failed to send sms message. Error Code: ${error.errorCode} / Error Message: ${error.errorMessage}`;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return "You are missing one of the variables you need to send a message";
    }
}
```

The I call this function from my index:

```
import { SQSEvent } from "aws-lambda";
import { sendSms } from "./services/sendSms/sendSms";
import { getSecret } from "./services/obtainSecrets/getSecret";
import { SecretsManager } from "aws-sdk";

export const lambdaHandler = async (event: SQSEvent) => {
    try {
        const obtainedSecret = await getSecret()
            .then((credentials: SecretsManager.GetSecretValueResponse) => {
                return credentials;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return error;
            });
        const response = sendSms(event, obtainedSecret)
            .then(response => {
                return response;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return error;
            });
        return {
            message: "OK " + obtainedSecret + response,
            code: 200,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
};
```

I have already make some tests, but them always makes a connection with Twilio api(requiring the real token, sid,etc), and I need to mock the Twilio service, so the function I call in my test.ts doesn't connects to internet.

```
import { Twilio } from "twilio";
import { MessageInstance } from "twilio/lib/rest/api/v2010/account/message";
import { sendSms } from "../../services/sendSms/sendSms";

//mock Twilio library and sendSms service
jest.mock("twilio");
jest.mock("../../services/sendSms/sendSms");

const smsMessageResultMock: Partial<MessageInstance> = {
    status: "sent",
    sid: "AC-lorem-ipsum",
    errorCode: undefined,
    errorMessage: undefined,
};
describe("SMS Service", () => {
    describe("Send Message", () => {
        it("Should fail", async () => {
            // update smsMessageResultMock to simulate a faled response
            const smsMessageMock = {
                ...smsMessageResultMock,
                status: "failed",
                errorCode: 123,
                errorMessage: "lorem-ipsum",
            };
            // simulated response of secret management
            let data = {
                ARN: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:123456789012:secret:MyTestDatabaseSecret-a1b2c3",
                Name: "MyTestDatabaseSecret",
                SecretString:
                    '{"TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID": "ACTWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID","TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN": "TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN","TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER": "TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER"}',
                VersionId: "EXAMPLE1-90ab-cdef-fedc-ba987SECRET1",
                VersionStages: ["AWSPREVIOUS"],
            };
            // simulated response of SqsEvent
            let event = {
                Records: [
                    {
                        messageId: "19dd0b57-b21e-4ac1-bd88-01bbb068cb78",
                        receiptHandle: "MessageReceiptHandle",
                        body: '{"message": "Hello world","number": "(506)88888888"}',
                        attributes: {
                            ApproximateReceiveCount: "1",
                            SentTimestamp: "1523232000000",
                            SenderId: "123456789012",
                            ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp: "1523232000001",
                        },
                        messageAttributes: {},
                        md5OfBody: "{{{md5_of_body}}}",
                        eventSource: "aws:sqs",
                        eventSourceARN: "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:MyQueue",
                        awsRegion: "us-east-1",
                    },
                ],
            };
            // simulate tokens for Twilio
            const accountSid = "ACfjhdskjfhdsiuy876hfijhfiudsh";
            const authToken = "fjfuewfiuewfbodfiudfgifasdsad";
            //create client with mocked Twilio
            const client = new Twilio(accountSid, authToken);

            //call messages.create of Twilio client, and give it the expected result created
            client.messages.create = jest
                .fn()
                .mockResolvedValue({ ...smsMessageMock });

            console.log(await sendSms(event, data));
            //expectes the function sendSms(event, data) to throw an error
            await expect(sendSms(event, data)).rejects.toThrowError(
                `Failed to send sms message. Error Code: ${smsMessageMock.errorCode} / Error Message: ${smsMessageMock.errorMessage}`
            );
        });
    });
});
```

(event and data are simulated responses of SqsEvent and GetSecretValueResponse)

The problem is that when I run the npm test it throws me an error of Twilio's authentication, an it is because I'm passing self created tokens.

```
 Expected substring: "Failed to send sms message. Error Code: 123 / Error Message: lorem-ipsum"                                             
    Received message:   "Authentication Error - invalid username"                                                                              
                                                                                                                                               
          at success (node_modules/twilio/lib/base/Version.js:135:15)                                                                          
          at Promise_then_fulfilled (node_modules/q/q.js:766:44)                                                                               
          at Promise_done_fulfilled (node_modules/q/q.js:835:31)                                                                               
          at Fulfilled_dispatch [as dispatch] (node_modules/q/q.js:1229:9)
          at Pending_become_eachMessage_task (node_modules/q/q.js:1369:30)
          at RawTask.Object.<anonymous>.RawTask.call (node_modules/asap/asap.js:40:19)
          at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
```

So what I suppose is that the test is connecting to internet and calling Twilio's api.

I appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's much easier to help if we have your existing test example that we can build from, rather than writing it from scratch for you.

Comment: You are right, my mistake, i will update the question

Comment: I added the index.test.ts, if you could give it a try, I will appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is mock the class returned by the module, using `jest.mock('twilio', mockImplementation)` and in `mockImplementation` return a function to act as a constructor that will take your account SID and auth token arguments and then return a `mockClient` implementation, which in this case needs to return an object which has a `messages` property, which in turn is an object with a `create` property that is a mock function.

It's probably easier to just show the code.

```js
const mockClient = {
  messages: {
    create: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ ...smsMessageMock });
  }
};

jest.mock("twilio", () => {
  return function(accountSid, authToken) {
    return mockClient;
  }
});
```